# Problems in Running Swirl Package _R

Tags: r, swirl

I was running the  "R Programming Basic Building Blocks", in the Swirl package. Everything was going well, until this point:

""Anytime you have questions about a particular function, you can access R's
| built-in help files via the `?` command. For example, if you want more
| information on the c() function, type ?c without the parentheses that
| normally follow a function name. Give it a try.""

I´d tried many and many times. just appeared the following message:

"" ?c
Error in shell.exec(url) :
access to 'http://127.0.0.1:31006/library/base/html/c.html' denied""

Even when I pressed "skip () ", it showed the correct answer and the same message:

""?c
Error in shell.exec(url) :
access to 'http://127.0.0.1:31006/library/base/html/c.html' denied""

| Leaving swirl now. Type swirl() to resume.

Anyone here know how to solve this problem?

TIA

Comment: I have tried, using `?c`, and was not able to reproduce this error with a new installation of `swirl`.  What happens if you use `?c` and `help(c)`, not inside the swirl course? It seems this issue has been raised [before](https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/issues/317), suggesting to run `options(help_type = "text")` before running swirl.

Comment: This isn't exactly an R problem. What is happening is that your IDE (are you using RStudio?) is trying to open a browser to the help page but the process does not have permission. Are you trying this on a corporate network? If you run `tools::startDynamicHelp()`, it should produce the output `starting httpd help server ... done`. Does it? If not you may need to get permissions from your sys admin, or just load the help pages from the web (e.g. [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/RHOME/library/base/html/c.html) for `c`).